# PHP Pass variable through URL using ?object=value

Tags: php, variables, get

I know there's a bunch of these topics out there, but all the answers are simply not working for me. I've tried everything I could find, and I'm still right where I started. I'm trying to pass a variable through a URL:

```
<a href="test2.php?one="<?php echo $_GET['one']; ?>">link</a>
```

When clicking on the "link", it redirects me to the appropriate page (test2.php), but leaves the value blank (resulting in localhost/test2.php?one=). This means I can no longer see what variable was being sent.

```
$one = $_GET['one'];
echo $one;
```

How can I properly send the variable from test.php to test2.php?

Comment: `<a href="test2.php?one="<?php echo $_GET['one']; ?>">link</a>`

should be:

`<a href="test2.php?one=<?php echo $_GET['one']; ?>">link</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotes from the `href` value:

```
<a href="test2.php?one=<?php echo $_GET['one']; ?>">link</a>
<!--                 ^^^ - quotes missing here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**you closed the href try this :**

```
<a href="test2.php?one=<?php echo $_GET['one']; ?>">link</a>
```